# Theorem 4 (Cayley-Hamilton), Section 6.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, determinant, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. If $f$ is the characteristic polynomial for $T$, then $f(T)=0$; in other words, the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynowlial for $T$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $K=\{f(T)\in L(V)\mid f\in F[x]\}$ is an commutative ring with identity. Of course, $K$ is actually a commutative linear algebra with identity over the scalar field. Choose an ordered basis $\{\alpha_l,…,\alpha_n\}$ for $V$, and let $A$ be the matrix which represents $T$ in the given basis. Then
> $$ T(\alpha_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ji}\alpha_j,\ \forall 1\leq i\leq n$$
> These equations may be written in the equivalent form
> $$\sum_{j=1}^n(\delta_{ij}T-A_{ji}I)\alpha_j=0,\ \forall 1\leq i\leq n$$
> Let $B$ denote the element of $M_{n\times n}(K)$ with entries $B_{ij}=\delta_{ij}T-A_{ji}I$. When $n=2$ $$B=\begin{bmatrix} T-A_{11}I & -A_{21}I \\ -A_{12}I & T-A_{22}I\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{align} \det (B) &= T^2-(A_{11}+A_{22})T+(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})I \\ &= T^2-\text{tr}(A)T+\det (A)I\\ &= f(T) \end{align}$$ where $f$ is the characteristic polynomial. For $n\gt 2$, it is also clear that $\det (B)=f(T)$, since $f$ is the determinant of the matrix $xI-A$ whose entries are the polynomials $$(xI-A)_{ij}=\delta_{ij}x-A_{ji}.$$
> We wish to show that $f(T)=0$. In order that $f(T)$ be the zero operator, it is necessary and sufficient that $(\det B)\alpha_k=0$ for $k=1,…,n$. By the definition of $B$, the vectors $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$ satisfy the equations $$\sum_{j=1}^n B_{ij}\alpha_j=0,\ \forall 1\leq i\leq n \tag{1}\label{1}$$
> When $n=2$, it is suggestive to write $\eqref{1}$ in the form $$\begin{bmatrix} T-A_{11}I & -A_{21}I \\ -A_{12}I & T-A_{22}I\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
> In this case, the classical adjoint, adj $B$ is the matrix $$\bar{B}= \begin{bmatrix} T-A_{22}I & A_{21}I \\ A_{12}I & T-A_{11}I\\ \end{bmatrix} $$ and $\bar{B}B=\begin{bmatrix}\det (B)& 0\\ 0& \det (B)\\ \end{bmatrix} =\det (B)\cdot I_2$. Hence, we have
> $$(\det (B)\cdot I_2)\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}=(\bar{B}B) \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}=\bar{B}\left( B \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right)= \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
> In the general case, let $\bar{B}=\text{adj} (B)$. Then by $\eqref{1}$
> $$\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\alpha_j=0$$ for each pair $k$, $i$, and summing on $i$, we have $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\alpha_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\right)\alpha_j.$$
> Now $\bar{B}B=\det(B)\cdot I_n$, so that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}=\delta_{kj}\det (B).$$
> Therefore $$0= \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{kj}\det (B)\alpha_j=(\det B)\alpha_k,\ \forall 1\leq k\leq n.$$

**Question:** **(1)** Since $\det (xI-A)=\det (xI-A)^t$, we have $f$ is determinant of matrix whose entries are the polynomials $[(xI-A)^t]_{ij}=(xI-A)_{ji}=\delta_{ij}x-A_{ji}$. How to “rigioursly” show $\det (B)=f(T)$?

**(2)** I don’t understand following step: Then by $\eqref{1}$
$\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\alpha_j=0$ for each pair $k$, $i$, and summing on $i$, we have $0=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\alpha_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\right)\alpha_j.$

What if we do following instead, inspired by $n=2$ case. We know $\bar{B}B=\det (B)\cdot I_n$. So $$(\det (B)\cdot I_n)\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix}=(\bar{B}B) \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix}=\bar{B}( B \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix} )=\bar{B}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \vdots \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $$(\det (B)\cdot I_n)\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \det (B)& & \\ &\ddots & \\ & & \det (B)\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$ Hence $(\det B)\alpha_k=0$, $\forall 1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: For (2), the only difference between your version and the version from the book is that you wrote it out as matrix equations, where the book expressed it as summations. It is the exact same calculation either way.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you so much for the answer. Yesterday I observed, $\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{B}_{ki}B_{ij}\right)\alpha_j=0$ is same as $k$th row of $(\bar{B}B) \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. But I couldn’t make sense of other summations.